# Fragment Activity leaves blank space in place of ActionBar in Overlay mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a FragmentActivity which contains two fragments. The main fragment shows users some reading material therefore occupies complete space of Activity. The other fragment contains some menu items and is right draggable. I want my ActionBar to be Overlayed above the contents of both fragments. I used

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)
```

before `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` method of my Activity.

It did overlayed the ActionBar but when actionBar auto-hides it lefts blanks space instead of contents to be displayed on full screen.

I GOOGLED and STACK OVER FLOWED and somebody here suggested to use this line in the `style.xml` in activity theme instead of one above I used.

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

But unfortunately It didn't helped either.

[image: It looks like below image]

I am stuck with it any help will be highly appreciated!